# checkboxes only appearing for first and last options

Tags: php

What the code does below is it retrieves individual options in a full option type. So for example if $option is A-D, then by using the explode, it will be able to display each individual option to output A B C D.

Now In this example I want A B C D to each have it's own checkbox. But with the code below it is just creating checkbox for A and D, the first and last options  when it should do it for `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`. How can this be done?

```
function ExpandOptionType($option) { 
    $options = explode('-', $option);
    foreach($options as $indivOption) {
        echo '<p><input type="checkbox" name="options[]" id="option-' . $indivOption . '" value="' . $indivOption . '" /><label for="option-' . $indivOption . '">' . $indivOption . '</label></p>';
    }
    if(count($options) > 1) {
        $start = array_shift($options);
        $end = array_shift($options);
        do {
            $options[] = $start;
        }while(++$start <= $end);
     }
     else{
        $options = explode(' or ', $option);
     }
     return implode(" ", $options);
}
```

Comment: what value does `$option` have?

Comment: put print_r($options) and check how many elements does it have.

Comment: By doing a print `$options`, it outputs this `Array ( [0] => A [1] => D ) ` while print '$option' shows `A-D`

Comment: If `$option` is `A-D` then your code will create two checkboxes, one for option `A` and one for option `D`. After that you change the contents op the `$options` array, so probably your order is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ExpandOptionType($option) { 
    $options = explode('-', $option);
    if(count($options) > 1) {
        $start = array_shift($options);
        $end = array_shift($options);
        do {
            $options[] = $start;
        }while(++$start <= $end);
     }
     else{
        $options = explode(' or ', $option);
     }
     foreach($options as $indivOption) {
         echo '<p><input type="checkbox" name="options[]" id="option-' . $indivOption . '" value="' . $indivOption . '" /><label for="option-' . $indivOption . '">' . $indivOption . '</label></p>';
     }
     return implode(" ", $options);
}
```

This way you first change the options array and then create the checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am not quite sure what the `if-else` in your function does, but is this what you are thinking about?

```
<?php foreach (range('A','D') as $letter): ?>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" id="option-<?php echo $letter ?>" value="<?php echo $letter ?>" />
    <label for="option-<?php echo $letter ?>"><?php echo $letter ?></label>
  </p>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Or, in a function:

```
function ExpandOptionType($from, $to) {
    $output = '';
    $range = range($from, $to);
    foreach ($range as $letter) {
        $output .= '<p>';
        $output .= "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"options[]\" id=\"option-{$letter}\" value=\"{$letter}\" />";
        $output .= "<label for=\"option-{$letter}\">{$letter}</label>";
        $output .= '</p>';
    }
    return $output;
}
echo ExpandOptionType('A', 'D');
```

Comment: The else statement is for option which have `or` in between rather than `-` The option isn't always gonna be A D, it could be A-C, A-H, A-Z. While if the options has the `or` in between then its `True or False` or `Yes or No`. If I do it function method then what should go in between the brackets `echo ExpandOptionType('A', 'D');`

Comment: Then you should have explained your problem in greater detail in your question.

Comment: I apologise for that, I just tried to provide a sample so you know how an option type and individual options are retrieved. Really all I want is except outputting A B C D as a string otput as it is now, I want to output it as checkboxes instead. But I want this for every possible option. Its got to be dynamic